# Ansible task variable fallback for with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm wondering if there's a way to instruct ansible to use the first variable found in a `with_items` parameter, for example:

```yaml
- name: install additional php.d ini files
  template: src=etc/opt/remi/php82/{{ item }} dest=/etc/opt/remi/php82/{{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ Server.Php82.AdditionalInis | Group.Php82.AdditionalInis | [] }}"
  notify:
   - restart apache
```

In the above example:

1. Use `Server.Php82.AdditionalInis` optionally defined in the host file, or;
2. Use `Group.Php82.AdditionalInis` optionally defined in a shared group file, or:
3. Skip the task, in that order.

Is something like this possible? I have seen `{{ var | default('my_var') }}` but it only supports a single fallback, as far as I could see.  I also don't know how to skip the task when nothing is found.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Just chain defaults: `"{{ Server.Php82.AdditionalInis | default(Group.Php82.AdditionalInis) | default([]) }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do two tasks with variable condition, like this:

```
- name: condition 1
  template: //smth//
  when: Server.Php82.AdditionalInis is defined

- name: condition 2
  template: //smth//
  when: (Group.Php82.AdditionalInis is defined and Server.Php82.AdditionalInis is not defined)
```

but chain-defaults in prev comment looks more smart :)

```
"{{ Server.Php82.AdditionalInis | default(Group.Php82.AdditionalInis) | default([]) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks - the chaining syntax works great.